# monitor local network traffic issue

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, bandwidth

I am using Networking Tab of Windows Task manager to monitor local network traffic to test how much bandwidth my application will use. My scenario is, I will use a local console client application to send data (using Http POST method) to local IIS 7.0 server.

My issue is no traffic could be monitored using Networking Tab of Windows Task manager. My environment is, VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + Windows Vista x86 Enterprise. Any ideas what is wrong?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3):

You might try [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), you can filter based on your exact requirements and get the bandwidth usage from that session.  Might take a little time to learn, but it will be very useful throughout your career as an Admin or Developer.

Comment: Thanks, in my experience, Wireshark could only monitor package content, could it be used to monitor bandwidth?

Comment: Ya, after the captures, I think from the top Menu, Statistics:Conversations might be what you want, but your version might be different.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry I have not made myself understood. Traffic I mean volumn, i.e. bps usage. I think wireshark could only monitor traffic content (e.g. TCP package headers and payloads), could it monitor bps?

Answer (score 1):

Try the free [FinitySoft Network Monitor](http://www.finitysoft.com/) to check data transfer rate and quantity across all your interfaces. It will show: download speed, upload speed, data transfered, IP address, MTU size, adapter type, MAC address, status and a few other choice morsels.

[Download page here.](http://www.finitysoft.com/download.php)

Comment: Networking Tab of Windows Task manager cannot monitor local network traffic, even if I access local IIS 7.0 server by using http://<local_machine_name>/xxx.aspx (I am not using localhost or 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: I have tried it does not work. Both download and upload speed are zero for software loopback interface. Can you have a try please?

Comment: It correctly logs my local throughput on "MS TCP Loopback interface [1]" - what do you see as the device name for IP address 127.0.0.1? If you're not using localhost, how are you routing traffic to your local machine?

Comment: Sorry Andy, I do not have a MS TCP Loopback interface [1], I only have software loopback interface, here is my screen snapshot. Do you mean this one? http://i25.tinypic.com/vgj4a1.jpg Thanks.

Comment: Lookback interfaces are virtual, and yes I mean that one. More columns in the screen grab would be useful. About the questions above; I can't help any further without that info.